# If $S$ be any set of intervals I in $\mathbb R$ and $J=\bigcap_{I \in S}I$ show $(\alpha,\beta)\subset J\subset [\alpha,\beta]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be a set of intervals $I$ in $\mathbb R$ s.t. $\exists I_1,I_2\in S$ where $I_1$ is bounded above and $I_2$ is bounded below.

If $J=\bigcap_{I\in S}I$ then show that $\exists \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb R$ with $\alpha\le \beta$ s.t. $(\alpha,\beta)\subset J \subset [\alpha,\beta]$

Comment: this is just nested interval theorem?

Comment: It seems to me that the statement is not true if their intersection is empty?

Comment: @EBP For empty $J$ we have $\alpha=\beta$.

Comment: But how is this nested interval theorem, even the intervals are not superset of each other  and their length is not approaching 0.

Comment: @Saikai Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc. Otherwise your question will likely be downvoted and closed by the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b$ be the right end-point of $I_1$ and $a$ be the left end-point of $I_2$. Clearly $I_1\cap I_2\subset [a,b]$ if $a\le b$. When $a>b,I_1\cap I_2=\emptyset$. Now $J=\bigcap_{I\in S}I\subset I_1\cap I_2$. Thus $J\subset [a,b]$ if $a\le b$ and $J=\emptyset$ if $a>b$. In any case $J$ is a bounded set in $\mathbb R$.

If $J=\emptyset$ then $(c,c)\subset J\subset [c,c] \,\,\forall c \in \mathbb R$. If $J$ is a singleton set, say $\{x\}$ then $(x,x)\subset J\subset [x,x]$.If $J$ contains more than one element, then $\exists x,y\in J$ s.t. $x<y$.  $J\subset I\,\,\forall I \in S \Rightarrow x,y\in I \,\,\forall I\in S$. Therefore $[x,y]\subset I\,\,\forall I\in S$ Hence $[x,y]\subset \bigcap_{ I\in S}I=J$.

By characterization theorem of intervals,  $J$ is an interval. As $J$ is a bounded interval it has a left end-point,say $\alpha$ and right end-point, say $\beta$ in $\mathbb R$ s.t. $(\alpha,\beta)\subset J\subset [\alpha, \beta]$.

Comment: Don't close the question, I think I got a glimpse of the question.  But my proof needs a bit improvement.